# ansible with_items will interpret

Tags: string, variables, eval, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm having an issue getting Ansible to dynamically select an inventory group from within a with_items block. I'm using ansible 2.

I've tried many variations, but I can't find a way to collect the group when I use a variable in part of the name. I would like to know if there is something like eval in ansible or jinja, which will allow me to access this, or another way I can get to an element within the groups variable dynamically

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cw_env: "pprod"
    group_name: "{{ 'groups.tag_environment_' + cw_env }}"

  tasks:
  - name: Test Group variable with items.
    debug: msg="{{ item }}"

    with_items: "{{ 'groups.tag_environment_' + cw_env }}"  # Gives STRING groups.tag_environment_pprod
    with_items: "groups.tag_environment_{{cw_env }}"        # Gives STRING groups.tag_environment_pprod

    with_items: "groups.tag_environment_pprod"              # WORKS - gives inventory group members
    with_items: "{{ groups.tag_environment_pprod }}"        # WORKS - gives inventory group members
```

Comment: I assume with_items: "{{group_name}}" works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no eval in Jinja/Ansible. But you should be able to access the group as

```
groups["tag_environment_%s"|replace("%s", cw_env)]
```

Comment: or groups["tag_environment_"+cw_env]